# Simulate powerbutton

Tags: tasker, automation, intents

I want to use terminal task to to turn the screen off using tasker. I have tried a code like this, and some variants, without success.

```
am start --user 0 -a android.intent.extra.KEY_EVENT --es KEYCODE_POWER ACTION_DOWN
```

I have also tinkered with

```
android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF
```

but with even less success.

Any ideas as how how I can get this to work? Either with terminal emulator or tasker *send intent* task?

Note: Not rooted, som shell task in will not work.

And System Lock doesn't work well with finger print reader

Answer (score 0):

By use `adb shell input keyevent <key_code>`
And for simulating your device power the key code is `26`

```
Adb shell input keyevent 26
```

Comment: Doesn't work on an unrooted device, when you want to do it on the device itself (not through adb)